# Что выведет здесь JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Изучаю JavaScript.Есть такой код:

```js
function getName() {
  var a;
  for (var a = 1; a < 10; a++) {
    return a;
  }
  return a;
}
getName();
```

Что здесь происходит и что он должен вывести? Я попробовал, у меня ничего не выводит.

Comment: Ну так тут и нет ни одного оператора вывода...

Comment: Функция возвращает единицу, ничего не выводит. console.log(getName()); например выведет возвращаемое функцией значение в консоль

Comment: @yolosora я написал так:console.log(getName(3)), но все равно выводит 1. Почему так?

Comment: @Timur потому что результат работы этой функции не зависит от передаваемых ей аргументов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас лишние объявление переменной на второй линии, не страшно но не нужно. Если есть желании использовать новый стандарт, рекомендую использовать в данном случае `let`.
Выведет у Вас 1, так как при первом вхождении в цикл у вас срабатывает конструкция `return`. Этим самым прерывая цикл и работы функции. В Вашем коде не возможно получить второй `return`, так как код функции "статический", т.е без настроек.

Comment: а что значит без настроек? Т.е какие настройки вообще можно сделать?

Comment: @Timur, под настройками я имел введу передача аргументов в функции или использования глобальных переменных.

Comment: @Timur А что вы хотите получить?

Comment: Куда выведет 1?

Comment: @Эникейщик "Куда кривая выведет." )